# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [4] Resource path is not callable

Tags: php, magento, soap

i have created a custom soap api in magento but when i try to use this custom api method named "customapimoduleProductList" , i get the following error

```
"Uncaught SoapFault exception: [4] Resource path is not callable"
```

The method "customapimoduleProductList" is added when i  visit http://yourmagentostore/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 for my store and
my other soap api methods are also working properly but facing issue for the custom one. Kindly Help. Refrence link for creating api which i have used is :
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-api-in-magento-part-one--cms-23785.

my code for reference :

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); require_once('../app/Mage.php'); umask(0); Mage::app(); $result4 = array(); //$category_id = $_POST['category_id']; $client = new SoapClient('magentostore.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); $sessionid = $client->__call('login',array('test', '12345678')); $result = $client->__call('customapimoduleProductList',array($sessioni‌​d)); var_dump($result); ?> and the error is "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [4] Resource path is not callable"
```

Comment: post your code and relevant error log

Comment: <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$result4 = array();
//$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.magentostore.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 
$sessionid = $client->__call('login',array('test', '12345678'));
$result = $client->__call('customapimoduleProductList',array($sessionid));
var_dump($result);
?> and the error is "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [4] Resource path is not callable"

Comment: @tanveer - Not as a comment - edit your post and put the code there. That way we can read it easily and it puts your question back to the top of the new posts list.